# Exiting Nested For loop VBA and re-looping

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to work with a nested For loop. I essentially have 2 arrays and I want to use the 1st variable in array1 with the 1st variable in array2 to do some operation, and so on until the array is exhausted. Unfortunately, the Exit For, doesn't exit for the For levels. So I've tried to use a goTo command, however then I get an error of  "This array is fixed or temporarily locked" clearly because I'm trying to re-access the array. I'm stuck how to get around this in VBA. Below is my code where at MsgBox some operation (that will need the pairs (dAFL,AFL),(dSF,SF), etc) will take place:

```
For Each vN In Array(dAFLcell, dSFcell, dSOcell, dFIGcell, dIBAcell, dIBXcell)
a = 0
For Each vN2 In Array(AFLcell, SFcell, SOcell, FIGcell, IBAcell, IBXcell)


If i = a Then
    MsgBox a
    GoTo end_of_for
End If
a = a + 1
Next vN2
end_of_for:
i = i + 1
Next vN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean flag - I don't know that it's the accepted method, but I use it from time to time.

```
Dim skipBool as Boolean = False    

For Each vN In Array(dAFLcell, dSFcell, dSOcell, dFIGcell, dIBAcell, dIBXcell)
    a = 0 'I think you want this out here, otherwise a will always equal 0
    For Each vN2 In Array(AFLcell, SFcell, SOcell, FIGcell, IBAcell, IBXcell)    
        If Not skipBool Then 'run this stuff only if we don't want to skip it (duh!)       

            If i = a Then
                MsgBox a
                skipBool = True 'set skipBool to be True (we want to skip it!)
            End If
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next vN2
    i = i + 1
    skipBool = False 'reset skipBool for the next go around
Next vN
```

I'm sure this code can be optimized a bit further (and to be honest, I haven't tested it), but it looks like this is what you're going for.

To be honest, the only problem might be that `a = 0` was inside the second for loop, and that's why you weren't getting the results you expected. It's been a while since I've used VBA (I've only been using VB.NET), so I don't remember the exact syntax there. I'd try fixing that, and going back to the exit for method. If it still doesn't work, my code should.

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I was going for. I should've tried a Boolean before posting. Thanks for your time. The issue with my way though, even with a=0 outside of the for loop, was the error that the array is locked with the goto. I don't quite understand the error but it's nice to have another way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Do you get the "array is fixed" error using `Exit For`? You shouldn't - and then, with the `a = 0` outside the first For Each, it should work exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: Using an Exit For with your solution gives a compile error. I'm not quite sure what you're asking :)

Comment: Will update when I get a chance. That said, if it ain't broke, don't fix it ;)

Comment: Yea I wouldn't worry about it haha

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible approach:

```
  Dim vn, Vn2 As Variant
  Dim i, min As Integer

  vn = Array(dAFLcell, dSFcell, dSOcell, dFIGcell, dIBAcell, dIBXcell)
  Vn2 = Array(AFLcell, SFcell, SOcell, FIGcell, IBAcell, IBXcell)

  If UBound(vn) <= UBound(Vn2) Then
    min = UBound(vn)
  Else
    min = UBound(Vn2)
  End If

  For i = LBound(vn) To min
    If vn(i) = Vn2(i) Then
      MsgBox vn(i)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
```

Comment: would this solution be more robust with 3 for loops?

Comment: Loops within loops mean x * y iterations...  fewer should be more efficient; not necessarily more robust, depending on what you want.  The way I read your question, you wanted to compare arrayA(1) to arrayB(1), arrayA(2) to arrayB(2).  If so, a single loop **should** do the trick.  Granted, we're talking a few records, not millions, so "efficient" is not that critical.

Comment: And I should mention it's possible I misread your requirement!

Comment: Yes in terms of my immediate problem it's only 2 arrays. However I had a thought at some point I might need a 3rd array to compare arrayA(1) to arrayB(1) to arrayC(1), and wondered if this would be a better way.

Comment: I see -- in that case, I think if you *can* get away with doing a single loop, I still think that might be most efficient.  If, for example, you had 100 elements in each array, the single loop iterates 100 times, whereas you would potentially have 100 x 100 x 100 iterations if you had three loops.  Of course, with short-circuiting it would end up being less than that, but you get the idea.  I did like the @charliefox2 solution and +1'ed it.  It was the most direct answer to your question/code.

Comment: @FancyDolphin I guess I didn't look at the code closely enough, but if the end goal was to compare elements of the same index in each array, then I feel that Hambone's solution is the better choice. However, with this solution, I would set `max` equal to the shorter of the two arrays, or you would get an out of bounds error if they were not of equal length. In terms of efficiency, this solution is also the better choice - 30 times out of 36, my solution simply skips the code. Hambone's runs exactly what you need.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I zigged when I should have zagged...  you are right; my `max` should be a `min`.  I'll fix that.  Good catch.

Comment: @FancyDolphin I would go with Hambone's answer on this one over mine - for what you are trying to do, this is the solution.

Comment: Don't "officially" change your choice.  That's hardly necessary -- a correct answer is still a correct answer.